# How can I make all my divs inside a grid have equal size when the grid changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 16x16 grid of divs,960 is the height and width of the area they are in, the divs are blocks 56px*56px usually, I want to make the size of the divs responsive to the changing of the grid size.
This is the jquery code I use to change the size of the grid

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('.unit').remove();

var rows=prompt("How many rows do you want?");
var columns=prompt("How many columns do you want?");
for(var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
        var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
        unit.appendTo('#container');
    }
}
        
$('.unit').css({
    width:function(){
        return (960/columns);
    },
    height:function(){
        return (960/rows);
    }

});
```

Comment: Why not use percentage widths in CSS, no javascript needed? 1/16 = 6.25%....

Comment: i think what he wants is. if a person only choses 1 column and 1 row, there should be 1 box of 960x960, if there are 2 row/column, it should be 4 boxes of 480x480

Comment: Well, the grid changes according to user input through jquery, how can i then connect the two?

Comment: it would be helpful if you made a jsfiddle so we can understand your problem easier

Comment: Yeah, what Abdul said, they need to be responsive.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L00jvyLq/

Comment: what's the problem with your code now? seems to work

Comment: No, I'm left with an uneven number of rows and collums, and they don't fill the 960px area correctly.

Comment: As your `.unit` have a 1px margin you have to substract 2px per unit from width and height. While padding is "eating away" the space from the given dimension, margins are "added on top" thus making your `units` 2px wider and higher than calculated. Try `(960-2*collumns)/collumns)` and analogous for height and rows.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

### responsive grid of squares, sized according to container size

css `grid` display is ideally suited to displaying a matrix of divs that will respond to any change in its container's size.

My snippet renders a grid of 16 rows, each with 16 squares, inside a div container that is styled to `display: grid`.

Each square is forced square (equal height and width) using an `aspect-ratio: 1` style rule;

By specifying a `grid-template-columns` rule for the container, the squares can be arranged in rows of 16, each having equal widths (and therefore heights). This is achieved by using fractional width units (`fr`) which basically divide up the available width automatically into however many fractions are specified. I have achieved this succinctly using a `repeat` rule:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
```

The template could also have been written:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

The `repeat` achieves the same.

Whatever the outside container div width is, the squares will re-size to 1/16 of the available space using this method. Note also, as used in my example, a gap can be introduced between the square divs if required without any need to recalculate square sizes, it's all taken care of by the grid-template-rows.

Demo:

```js
const outerGrid=document.querySelector('.grid-container');

for (let i=0; i<16*16; i++) {
  const innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerDiv.setAttribute('class', "inner_div");
  outerGrid.appendChild(innerDiv);
} // next inner div;
```

```css
.inner_div {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

<!-- (16 rows of 16 inner divs will be added dynamically to save me typing -->

</div>
```

To apply this simple solution to your example, you just have to specify a size for the container division to your starting width. The squares will be sized automatically. When you change the outer div size (by *any* method), the inner squares will automatically resize and keep their 16x16 arrangement.